# integration quick $\int \frac{2x^2+x+1}{(x-1)^2(x+3)} dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int \frac{2x^2+x+1}{(x-1)^2(x+3)} dx$$

I got my solution as $$= - \frac{1}{x-1} + \ln(x-1) + \ln(x+3) + C$$

Wolfram got $$\frac{1}{1-x} + \ln(1-x) + \ln(3+x) + C$$ Which is different from mine. Am i right?

Comment: Well the first term is no different, that's for sure.

Comment: In main integral we have $x+3$ but other show $x-3$.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be $(x-3)$ rather than $(x+3)$ in the denominator of the original integral? Because otherwise, neither your answer nor WolframAlpha's would look like they do.

Comment: Note that $\ln(x-1) +\ ln(x-3) = \ln (x-1)(x-3) = \ln(1-x)(3-x) = \ln(1-x) + \ln(3-x)$ You would choose the representation that has you computing the natural logarithm of a positive number.

Comment: You probably want $| |$. Then it gives the same result because $\ln |x-1|=\ln |1-x| $ as $|x-1|=|1-x|$.

Comment: Sorry you are right, both ours is (x+3) I made a typo

Comment: I think one should first discuss the interval one wants a primitive for. Then find the primitive. Do you have an interval?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, Wolfram Alpha is right.

Answer (score 3):

If you recall $\int\frac{1}{x}\text{d}x=\ln\color{red}|x\color{red}|+C$ so similarly $\int\frac{1}{x-1}=\ln|x-1|+C$. Because of the equality of $|-x|=|x|$ we can also rewrite the $\int\frac{1}{x-1}$ as $\ln|1-x|+C$ as for the $\frac{1}{x-1}$, factoring out a -1 yields $-\frac{1}{1-x}$. So you are indeed correct due to those absolute value signs on the natural log.

Answer (score 1):

It must be $\frac{1}{1-x} + \ln|1-x| + \ln|3+x| + C$

The right answer is $$\frac{1}{1-x} + \ln(x-1) + \ln(x+3) + C_1$$ for $x>1$ or $$\frac{1}{1-x} + \ln(1-x) + \ln(x+3) + C_2$$ for $-3<x<1$ or
$$\frac{1}{1-x} + \ln(1-x) + \ln(-x-3) + C_3$$ for $x<-3$.

Comment: PFD gives A = 1, B = 1 and C = 1 ? how does it become ln |1-x| ?

Comment: @user349557 $\frac{2x^2+x+1}{(x-1)^2(x+3)}=\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x+3}$

Comment: How is my answer wrong?

Comment: @user349557 Without $|\cdot|$ your answer is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: not really. WA also gives an answer without the absolute values, which is compensated by $i\pi$ terms.

Comment: @Yves Daoust We need to find a real integral! :)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: In fact using the complex form is attractive as the imaginary constant will not vanish when you integrate across the singularities, raising an alarm. I would tend to follow WA.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you are both right, as your answers only differ by an imaginary constant, provided you use the complex definition of the logarithm, with an extra $i\pi$ term for the negatives (which you maybe didn't intend).

It is more common to use the logarithm of the absolute value, which leaves you in the reals.

Whatever the convention, recall that you are not allowed to compute definite integrals across the changes of sign, as this corresponds to improper integrals. (Actually, the difference between these conventions is only piecewise constant.)